# How to disable this button for 5 sec after first click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code the button .getmore  gets clicked on scroll down. It loads data from database.Works fine. I need to make it disable for 5 sec after every click. How can I set this delay timer?

Or is it possible to disable this function for 5 sec once it fires?  Disable the button or disable the function anything will work for me.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(document).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
        // Here how can i set a delay time of 5 sec before next click 
        $('.getmore').click(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Although I know what you are trying to achieve, wouldn't be better to add an event listener rather than using a fixed amount of time and keep the button disabled until the server responds?

Comment: use setTimeout(function(){$('.getmore').click(); },"5000")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use setTimeout() function of jQuery.

```
 $('.getmore').prop('disabled', true);
 setTimeout(function() {
       $('.getmore').prop('disabled', false);
 }, 5000);
```

Comment: okay i have pasted this after  $('.getmore').click();  . It's working first time after that it's back to the same problem.  how can i disable it after every click

Comment: In that case, you need to bind a [handler](https://api.jquery.com/click/) with the click event which will call this code.

Comment: ok thanks man ........ it works for 5 sec with this code.    .... so  i just increased the time for 30 mins and it's working perfectly.

Comment: do me a fever  please can you tell me why my question got down voted ? then i can be careful in future

Comment: Because it is a very basic question, you could have googled first before posting in SO. :)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use [setTimout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) and [disable the button with javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_button_disabled.asp) using `document.getElementById("yourButtonID").disabled = true;`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a flag inside the clickHandler:

```js
var clickHandler = () => {
  if (clickHandler.running)
    return
  
  clickHandler.running = true
  setTimeout(() => { clickHandler.running = false }, 5000)
  
  console.log(new Date())
  }

$('#getmore').click(clickHandler)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='getmore'>more</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

U can use setTimeout() n after that, put ur disable button function inside it.

setTimeout(document.getElementById('ur_button_id').style.display = 'none', 500);